# Core Data: "Persistent store is not reachable from this NSManagedObjectContext's coordinator"

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a (iOS 14.5) app that uses a sqlite data store with two `ManagedObjectContext`s. One for the UI and one for background processing.

Setup looks like this (whith PersistanceController being the auto-generated one):

```
let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

//Setup Background Context
let backgroundContext = persistenceController.container.newBackgroundContext()
backgroundContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
backgroundContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy(merge: .mergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicyType)

// Setup View Context
persistenceController.container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
persistenceController.container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy(merge: .mergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicyType)
```

I my code I am retrieving a `NSManagedObject` on my `viewContext` which perfectly works, is not a fault and can be read/displayed. However, when I take that object and try to pass it to my background context via:

`let objectInBackground = backgroundContext.object(with: objectFromViewContext.objectID)`

I get

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Object 0x88fe03855b097dd8 <x-coredata://3A2EE926-B0E9-4D08-B508-FEA5585FDFFZ/MyEnityName/p2207> persistent store is not reachable from this NSManagedObjectContext's coordinator'*`

Interestingly, I have tons of multi-threaded code in my app and this works all the time but I have one entity that reproducibly generates this exception. Other objects can be retrieved using exactly the same code. I am wondering if this might be a bug within Core Data or the object being somehow "corrupted"? I am grasping at straws here because there is nothing different from this object to others for which the code works.

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you doing anything that would affect the store besides reading and writing? Deleting it or trying to reset it somehow?

Comment: I solved this problem although it is not an answer to the question: -- I was handing the `backgroundContext` via a SwiftUI environment variable but it seems that the variable sometimes (tm) is not handed down correctly.